# Error when using "diff" function inside of dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

I try to `mutate` new column to data.frame. When `V` column order changes from decreasing to increasing order, I use `diff` function inside of `mutate` to categorize them in new column `H`.

```
V <- c(seq(30,-10,-10),seq(-10,30,10))
gr = rep(seq(1,3),each=10)
df <- data.frame(V,gr)

library(dplyr)    
diff_df <- df%>%
  group_by(gr)%>%
  mutate(H=ifelse(diff(V)<0,"back","forward"))
```

However getting error

```
Error: incompatible size (9), expecting 10 (the group size) or 1
```

But when I do

> diff(df$V)

[1] -10 -10 -10 -10   0  10  10  10  10   0 -10 -10 -10 -10   0  10  10  10  10   0 -10 -10 -10 -10   0  10  10  10  10

seems to be working logically. Why I'm getting error when I do inside of `dplyr?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need to concatenate with one more value to make the length equal as `diff` returns with a length one less than the length of the group. i.e.

```
length(df$V)
#[1] 30
length(diff(df$V))
#[1] 29
```

So, we concatenate with a dummy number at the beginning to make the `length` equal.

```
 df %>%
   group_by(gr) %>%
   mutate(H=ifelse(c(0,diff(V))<0,"back","forward"))
```

If we need the first value to be 'back', change the condition to `<=0`

Comment: A more `dplyr`-y alternative would be to replace `diff` with `V - lag(V)`. (or perhaps `V - lag(V, 1, 0)`)

Comment: How would you do this for mutate_each?

Comment: @jhilliar  The `mutate_each` will soon becomes replaced. `df %>% group_by(gr) %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(c(0, diff(.)) < 0, "back", "forward")))`