# (base R) How to apply `diff()` to a column and append it as a new data.frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I have a data frame `df1` like this:

| time | Diamond.Hands | returns | volume | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-16 10:00:00 | 0.4583333 | 0.0056710775 | 10059 | 53.20 |
| 2021-02-16 11:00:00 | 0.2352941 | -0.0037586920 | 8664 | 53.01 |
| 2021-02-16 12:00:00 | 0.4400000 | -0.0037586920 | 10059 | 52.40 |

```
# Log return
prices <- df1$close
log_returns <- diff(log(prices), lag=1)
df1$logreturns <- log_returns
```

returns the error:

```
Fehler in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, logreturns, value = c(0.000187952260679136,  :
  Ersetzung hat 2219 Zeilen, Daten haben 2220
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
y <- diff(x, lag = m, differences = k)
```

the resulting vector `y` has `m * k` fewer elements than `x`. If you want to have both `x` and `y` as data.frame/matrix columns, you need to pad `m * k` number of leading NAs to `y`.

In your case, `m = 1` and `k = 1`, so you need to pad one NA:

```
df1$logreturns <- c(NA, log_returns)
```

More concisely, we can pack your 3 lines of code into 1:

```
df1$logreturns <- c(NA, diff(log(df1$close)))
```

---

**Remark:**

If you want to know how to do `mutate()` + `diff()` in **dplyr**, then maybe something like:

```
df1 %>% mutate(logreturns = c(NA, diff(log(close))))
```

Here is another possibly related Q & A: [Error when using "diff" function inside of dplyr mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35169423/4891738).